# Sorting on data, not in columns, in Slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Is it possible to sort the gird based on data provided to the Dataview, but that is not present in the grid? 
On data that I have not provided a column for that is.

Say the data looks like this

```
data = [ {id: 1, name: "foo", other: "asd", hiddenSortData: "AA"},
         {id: 2, name: "bar", other: "bbb", hiddenSortData: "BB"}, {...}];
```

and columns:

```
columns = [{id: "id", name: "id", field: "id"},
           {id: "name", name: "name", field: "name"},
           {id: "other", name: "other", field: "other"}];
```

And after the data is provided to the dataview, is it possible to sort the grid based on the 'hiddenSortData' property in the data item?

Comment: ...and have you tried it? I think it would actually be easier to sort the data at the source, meaning from the SQL or whatever dataset you get it from.

Comment: this is embarrassing since I have not tried it. But from reading the documentation it seems to me that the sorting in the dataview is done with something called "args.sortCol" in the onClick event. Which is why I asked the question. But making calls to the database everytime I want to sort the grid doesn't seem right to me..? I thought that Dataview in slickgrid existed partly for sorting the grid.

Comment: Bear in mind that I am relatively new to web programming, so I apologize if any comment seems "Nooby"..

Comment: the sortdir and sortcol are for sorting the data per the column you clicked on. You are using a hidden column so it will never trigger that part... as I said before, it would be much easier to sort your data prior to displaying it, which is directly in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-querying the source data (SQL or whatever) to re-sort and lose all the unsaved changes in the grid you have two options: Use the [sort()](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView#sorting) function in dataView but you have to figure out how to hid that column, or pull the data out of dataView, sort it, present it back to dataView and re-render the grid (no page reloads are required.)